# How to send data from a Windows Form Application to a Asp.Net Web Service Application

Tags: c#, web-services, visual-studio-2010

I have a Windows Form Application connected to a database. It does some simple select operations and shows the result on the DataGridView.

I want to send that data on the grid to a web service. I did some research on the Internet about web services and found that I can easily creat a web service, define its methods and use these methods from my Windows Form Application by using Visual Studio 2010. Unfortunately, that is not what I want. I already have a Windows Form Application with some methods in it. All I want is to send the data (xml) to a web service that I created in Visual Studio. How can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET VB -- How to consume web service with WSDL file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1209779/asp-net-vb-how-to-consume-web-service-with-wsdl-file)

Answer (score 0):

See "[How to Consume a Web Service](http://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2009/05/17/how-to-consume-a-web-service/)".