# Using a WebService From Another Project in my own project in C#

Tags: c#

Hello i'm trying to add a webservice to my project, and that web service is from another project i have open. IIS is set up and everything works good with the webService.
Ok so on first image ,im using the webservice in the same project i have it created and it works fine
http://img215.imageshack.us/img215/4605/55347669.jpg
On second image i add the webreference and it is added succesfully . Thing is i dont know how to access it ( the HelloWorld function that returns a string which i want to set up to be text for the label )
http://img846.imageshack.us/img846/4922/19350256.jpg
The error i get at the second image says
" BankarskiUslugi is a namespace but it is used as type."
So i would appreciate any help if someone tells me how can i 'call' the webservice in my proect.
Thanks a lot in advance !

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to consume web service with WSDL file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1209779/how-to-consume-web-service-with-wsdl-file)

Answer (score 0):

When you added the web service reference, it should have shown a namespace for the web service you were referencing; you need to add something like:

```
using YourWebServiceNamespace;
```

And then you should be able to instantiate it and call the methods as you are trying to do on the second image.

Comment: i added the namespace
using BankarskiUslugi;
but still i dont know how to instantiate it

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use WCF Test Client (WcfTestClient.exe) as far as testing is concern.

Answer (score 0):

See [How to Consume a Web Service](http://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2009/05/17/how-to-consume-a-web-service/).