# Sending SOAP requests in C#

Tags: c#, .net, soap

I am trying to consume a SOAP service in C#, so I added my WSDL as a Service Reference. So far, I have created an instance of the request I want to send, but I don't know how to send it, or process the response.

Can someone explain how to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to consume web service with WSDL file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1209779/how-to-consume-web-service-with-wsdl-file)

Comment: In what way does it not answer your question? It's exactly what you asked.

Comment: The duplicate tells you how to send requests. Please actually read it.

Comment: It says, "See "[How to Consume a Web Service](http://johnwsaundersiii.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!600A2BE4A82EA0A6!790.entry)"."

Comment: Yes, please delete this post. Based on the answers, future readers will be doing all the wrong things. Did you seriously not read the blog post? Was it too long?

Comment: There are answers here on using ASMX and using WSE, and I'm concerned someone will use them. I recommend that when you get a chance, you create a blog post on this topic that would have answered your question. Or maybe instead of deleting the question, add an answer to say what you feel the answer was and why you had a problem. Feel free to accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you added the service reference, Visual Studio should generate some code for you, including a class for the service which is in its own namespace.

So, you need to create a new instance of this service:

```
var oService = new ServiceNamespace.ServiceClient();
```

Then you can call your methods on the service:

```
oService.SomeMethod();
```

Comment: Was assuming it was a web reference. Have fixed answer for service reference.

Answer (score 0):

here you can find the full documentation and sample:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa529276.aspx

Comment: that page doesn't seem to mention what to do when I am using the Web Service as a Service Reference

Comment: i skimmed it, but I can assure you its not what I am looking for. Before asking this question, I tried to follow its instructions

Comment: Thanks for reminding this (just saw your post on http://social.msdn.microsoft.com) last time I needed to use WSE was on 2005 and never had a need since...then..

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/34279-introduction-to-web-services-in-c%23/) is a full example of How you create a WebService and How to consume it. As I see you just need the part of how to consume it. But it is like a normal call function you send parameters and receieve a result parsed to an object. Sometimes Value Objects created by the Service Reference Tool. Hope it helps.

By the way it uses the Web reference, with a service reference is quite similar just the name of your Class is parsed with a `SoapClient` at the End, lets say that your service is named `Foo`, the Service reference will generate it for you like `FooSoapClient`

Comment: -1 for posting 1) how to use the wrong technology, and 2) how to pass platform-specific objects using a web service, thereby violating the principles of SOA.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Upon closer look at the code generated by VS, I found the client and now I've got it working.